# XLogger on Xiaomi?

Tags: encryption, xiaomi, logging, miui-12

Installed a simple file explorer on my pocket telescreen, Xiaomi MI 8 Pro, right now is running on unrooted MIUI 12.04

It happens that I have found a .log file, (completely by accident)
with hundreds of entries, day by day but they are encrypted somehow.

Here is the sample, mostly all look like this:

```
LV:I, TM: 2020-12-10 19:26:37, TAG: ##XLogger##, MSG: #&^hNNLFjwHJGwbUDpLDrj5urK+b6mXPcFQNJvkXgL5SVPxtfZBOzyPpBFgPDEUxllkC+FxzWWV2HyrPe0UE6F3ml9RFkJ4/kzHAnrdxHL4z5++zba4l8tq6w7WIqcmYEGbMkSfPnpErw7JTmIwvqer7t8uJJwn8NSHUmAFA49PiFg=!!JU07CfBL9bt46QcTJLLe9RN0juHv6fnuDUFD0yagTM9wm0gJxrWzy9zNOxSXpLJBOSBMw/2wJ1eGFj5VZqcjYmCidBHV4JR7IXMwfayEy7bVw0z98Fje1Eb5PymyU4RqosTTuF/V85pPRAvUscI1GwKAZogwuGlM776r84QJh0X3xcccccccccvvvvvvvvvvv+rX^&#
```

How can I open and or decode them?

Comment: I also have such logs on my old Redmi Note 4, Android 7 (MIUI 11?), in folders files like `/device/MIUI/debug_log/common/com.xiaomi.finddevice`.

Comment: Same happened to me today! Found "1.log" with encrypted log off like 2 weeks.
I'm using a Redmi 8a with MIUI 12.